# Setting the Location of Django Templates

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

So I am trying to learn Django by modifying the tutorial program, this is version 1.9, by the way.

I have my project folder, called mud, and then my app folder, polls. Inside the polls app there's a template folder, which then circles back to the polls folder. When I want to create a template I just put it there. I also wanted to create a template for my main homepage, which would be outside the polls.

I tried to make a template folder inside of the base MUD folder, as well as the mud/mud folder, and neither works. I always get the error when it's looking for the index.html of...

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/andaib/themudreport.com/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/mud/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/andaib/themudreport.com/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/mud/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/andaib/themudreport.com/mud/polls/templates/mud/index.html (Source does not exist)

It seems to only be looking inside the mud/polls... for a mud/polls/mud.

This to me seems crazy disorganized, and I'm sure there's got to be a way to add to the list of folders I'm trying to access for templates, but inside my settings.py I'm not finding it. Maybe someone can assist? This feels like a 2 second fix for someone more experienced with django.

```
"""
Django settings for mud project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '=gc!jwa)#q%8t&cl^wi3ago!=dq)ws)xtg5h1s_mgb75q$@uzm'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]


ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
                  ]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mud.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mud.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '*****',
        'USER': '*****',
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
        'HOST': '*****',
        'PORT': '*****',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR) + '/public/static/'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
        },
    },
]
```

This syntax has been deprecated in Dj v1.9

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

Comment: I already have the TEMPLATE_DIRS list on line 28, do I need to delete the TEMPLATES list as well?

Comment: Thank you both, a combination of your answer and his answer did it! Deleted the Templates list like you said and added the 'mud' to the join like he did.

Answer (score 2):

Templates in your `/polls/templates/` folder are found because `polls` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. The app directories folder will not search `/mud/templates` or `mud/mud/template`, because `mud` and `mud/mud` are not apps.

If you want to add templates to `/mud/templates`, then add it to your `DIRS` option of the `TEMPLATES` setting.

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Similarly, if you wanted templates in `/mud/mud/templates`, you would do:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mud', 'templates')],
```

Comment: I already have that line in the code. Should I delete the Templates list like in Du D suggestion?

Comment: Remove the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` line, then change the `DIRS` **inside** `TEMPLATES` (at the moment you have `'DIRS': [],`)

Comment: Thank you both! A combination of your two answered did it!